# Deploy asp.net and PHP Application in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, web-deployment, magento-2.0

Our main product is an asp.net application which is having MS SQL Server for db and this application in deployed in the root location under our domain.
Now requirement come for a sub domain or child application inside existing domain location, but new application will be created on PHP with Magento framework will have My-SQL as db.

**Here is My question


Is IIS able to serve request for Magento as child or sub domain application with existing asp.net application environment?
Or will I need to install any component to support Magento environment?**

*Our target will to crate environment for development along with QA and Live server environment with this behavior.*

Need suggestions!!!

Answer (score -2):

PHP is supported in IIS after installing an additional components.  Check out the [PHP in IIS](http://php.iis.net/) web site.  And here is older [tutorial](http://tarunjadav.blogspot.com/2013/09/magento-run-on-iis-and-installation.html) for setting up Magento.

You can install [PHP](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP53) via the Web Platform Installer.  Once PHP is installed you will be able to create another website or child app to deploy the Magento site to along with ASP.NET sites.

Comment: Agree with DavidYee, @chief7 please provide solutions for query here only.